# The benefit of dynamic_cast on variant classes

Tags: c++, variant, dynamic-cast

Why is almost any `class variant` solved with `dynamic_cast` instead of 
`static_cast` with a manual type check?

Isn't `dynamic_cast` actually much slower than `static_cast` even if you additional check types manual or is there another benefit of it which I miss?
(I know that `dynamic_cast` is usual taken for polymorphic objects)

Is there something for `variant classes` which can't be checked with `std::type_info` objects?

Comment: "much slower" is subjective.  Dynamic casts effectively insert an extra branch into the code, which on a modern CPU is pretty much unmeasurable, and in most cases is exceeded by the pointer accesses you will make.  Always profile before making performance decisions about your code.

Comment: One major variant implementation, boost's, does not use `dynamic_cast` but rather a visitor. Can you please clarify if your question is about static vs dynamic casts, or more specifically about variants, and if so provide more concrete information about the implementations that confuse you?

Comment: It's more about the connection to `variant classes` because I can't get the reason why `dynamic_cast` is so often used for ` variant classes`. I know it check's the types of the classes before it casts, but aren't there better or more effektiv possibilities for implementing a variant class?